# How to display results coming from database in 3 columns using php/mysql/html/css

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I am using PHP and MySQL to get data from database. My function is returning me array of objects. I am looping through them, and would like to display them in 3 columns. I have tried with CSS column-count property, but there is a problem that if number of results is even, results will be displayed in 2 columns, only if they are odd, they will be in 3 columns. I am using Bootstrap 3 also.

Here is my output code:

```
<div class="content">

    <div class="col-lg-12 offer">     
        <ul class="cpv">

        <?php foreach ($model as $data): ?>
            <li>
                <?= Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/img/170713.jpg', ['class' => 'img-responsive']) ?>
                <br> <?= $data->post->author?> <br>
                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a> &nbsp;
                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> (<?= $count ?>)</a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"> </div>

</div>
```

Technologies that I am using are : PHP, MySQL, Yii2 PHP framework, HTML, CSS, Bootstrap 3.

How would you display data in 3 columns, without this problem that even number of results will be displayed in 2 columns instead of 3?

Comment: `<table>`, `<div style="display: table-cell">`, `<div>` with flexbox. Take your pick.

Comment: erm... what ? what is flexbox ? and where should my dynamic code go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  element with bootstrap 3 class 'col-md-4' or 'col-lg-4'

Comment: Yes this work. I have added class="col-lg-4" to <li>. Thanks!